# Diffie-Hellman key exchange - why is modulo operation necessary?

Tags: key-exchange, diffie-hellman

Could someone explain why it's necessary to have the modulo operation in the Diffie-Hellman key exchange?

Let's imagine we do DH without the modulo operation ($A = g^a, B = g^b$). Would that not work, because the logarithm ($a = \log_gA$) is easy to calculate? And why does the modulo operation have to be done with a prime?

I know it's a basic question, sorry. I understand the protocol, but not the maths around what is easy to calculate and what isn't. I guess we need $A = g^a \bmod p$ instead of just plain $A = g^a$, because $\log_gA \bmod p$ is very hard to calculate... would it be easy to calculate it without the $\bmod p$?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't sample uniformly at random from an infinite set (among other things).

Comment: @SEJPM DH doesn't really require uniformly random sampling. Typically you a ~256 bit private key together with a 2048-bit safe-prime.

Comment: watch this series of short videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLP6PHJ8SLR6AA93UEXGaDFUDc8paCCsiD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would that not work, because the logarithm ($a=\log_gA$) is easy to
>   calculate?

Yes, among other things.

- [We know how to efficiently calculate the logarithm over real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Computational_complexity) (thus this would bear no security).
- We can't sample uniformly at random from an infinite range (all natural numbers), that means you can't randomly draw a natural number because every single one will have $0$ probability of being drawn. This makes key-generation hard (yes one could technically limit the length here).
- We can't store, let alone transmit, such large numbers. For example assume $g=3$ and now pick a standard-size DH exponent $a$ which has 2048-bit length. $g^a$ will now have $1.5\cdot 2^{2048}$ bit length. We can't store that. [We can't even *count* to $2^{192}$ realistically](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1160/23623) (with counting being easier than storing).

> And why does the modulo operation have to be done with a prime?

There are a few reasons (why to prefer primes):

- It gives us nice mathematical properties. $\mathbb F_p$ is a [*field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), that is every element has a multiplicative inverse, whereas $\mathbb Z_n$ is a [*ring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) where not every element has a multiplicative inverse.
- It prevents backdoors. If you pick a composite value, the person who knows the factors *will have a significantly easier time to compute the logarithm*. Picking a prime ensures there's no doubt about anybody knowing any factors if you re-use parameters.

Comment: Why would you use >256 bits for the DH exponent $a$? (What standards do that?)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage While I prefer 256 bit exponents, some prefer to use the full range up to the order because it relies on a weaker hardness assumption (though in this case it's not helpful, since we don't operate in a finite group). See [Diffie-Hellman, random number size](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39464/diffie-hellman-random-number-size).

Comment: "We can't store, let alone transmit, such large numbers". Calculating $2^{2048}$ in Python produces 2049 bits: `bin(2**2048)`. While I agree that enumerating each value from 0 to $2^{2048}$ takes too long, I'm pretty sure we can store and transmit more than two kibibytes. Is there something I'm missing in that argument on storing numbers such as $2^{2048}$?

Comment: @MatthiasBraun you're missing an exponentiation there. If you exponentiate $g=3$ with a number of the range of $2^{2048}$ you get a number in the range of $3^{(2^{2048})}$ which is $2^{2048}$ bits long (with us currently being able to store less than $2^{80}$ bits).

Comment: @SEJPM: Indeed, I missed the base number. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons we do operations modulo a prime $p$ is because it enables us to have a group structure where every element $x < p$ will have an inverse $x^\prime$ such that $xx^\prime \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. We also have efficient algorithms to compute $x^d \pmod{p}$.

Another reason is that $x^d$ with a $d$ of a large size would be impossible to compute as the result would have too many digits. For example, a big number $x \approx 2^{256}$ to the power $d \approx 2^{256}$ would be $256*2^{256}$ bits long which is [impossible to store](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1160/23623) let alone compute.