# Why is Diffie-Hellman Insecure If Order of the Generator Has Only Small Prime Factors?

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, attack, key-size

In [this post from security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54359/what-is-the-difference-between-diffie-hellman-generator-2-and-5/54367#54367), Tom Leek mentioned that, for Diffie-Hellman to be secure order of the group $g$ should have a prime factor at least $2k$ bits long, where $k$ is the security parameter.

Why is it so? Order of $g$ has to be large, otherwise, the discrete log would be easy. But I couldn't see any other reason why the order of $g$ should have a large prime factor. And why should it be at least $2k$ bits long (instead of $k$ bits long)?

It also says the private keys $a$ and $b$ should also be $2\text{k}$ bits long. They should be large, otherwise, the discrete log would be easy. But why should they be $2\text{k}$ bits long, instead of $\text{k}$ bits long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - But I couldn't see any other reason why the order of g should have a large prime factor.

Let $p$ be the Diffie-Hellman modulus. The order $q$ of the subgroup generated by $g$ must have at least one large prime factor to prevent the use of [Pohlig–Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm). The complexity of this algorithm $$\mathcal O\left(\sum_i {e_i(\log n+\sqrt p_i)}\right)$$ where $e_i$ is the power of the prime factor $p_i$. In short, the larger one of the $p_i$s the higher complexity.

> - Why should it be at least 2k bits long (instead of k bits long)?

The $\text{k}$-bit is the required for the target security. The [generic attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms) on Discrete logarithm problem have $\mathcal{O}(2^\text{k/2})$ complexity thus you need to start at least from $2\text{k}$.

**Note:** The safe primes $p = 2q+1$  guarantees that the order of $g$ is $q$ or $2q$.

> - It also says the private keys a and b should also be 2k bits long.

No, the $2\text{k}$-bit for the choice of $a$ and $b$ is not necessary. As you can see from this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39505/18298);

> The *standard* Decisional Diffie-Hellman assumption holds for the case that $g^{x_a}$ and $g^{x_b}$ are *uniformly distributed* in the group (which should be a prime-order subgroup).

There is also a linked article ([Short Exponent Diffie-Hellman Problems](https://www.iacr.org/archive/pkc2004/29470171/29470171.ps)) for this issue in the comments of this the answer.

Comment: Why should $g^{x_a}$ and $g^{x_b}$ be uniformly distributed in a "prime-order" subgroup? What happens if the order of the subgroup is composite?

Comment: Since order of $g$ is at least 2k bits long, it means we need to chose $x_a$ and $x_b$ to be at least 2k bits long right?

Comment: @satya Did you read the [linked article](https://www.iacr.org/archive/pkc2004/29470171/29470171.ps)?